# I can not open the webcam using VideoCapture of cv2

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on project about vehicles detection and counting, and i'm trying to use trained HAAR cascade provided by opencv using anaconda3, but cv2.VideoCapture(0).isOpened() return False, means that it couldnt open the frames correctly,what should i do ? thank you.

I've already tried to change the parameter 0 to -1 as recommended on the net but it didn't work :/

```py
import cv2
import  numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.isOpened() 
#This one returns False !
```

Comment: Have you tried `cap.open(0)`?

Comment: @TechPerson yes, and it returns False too :/

Comment: That would suggest that either your camera is not connected or OpenCV cannot use it due to driver issues. Does the camera work in any other programs?

Comment: Hi @HananeTriy! What operating system are you currently using by the way?

Comment: @harriebird Hello there, I'm using Widows 7

Comment: Try to check if your webcam is detected by the operating system you are currently using. On windows, open the device manager and check if there is a webcam listed under **Imaging devices** category.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the problem with the driver.
You could test if your camera works well in other applications.
It occured to me once on my Ubuntu16.
For Linux, you could use cheese or command line:

```
ls  /dev/video*
```

to see if your camera is mounted.

For Windows, just open you camera application. But I think the camera driver could barely fail on Windows

Comment: Actually, i found that my camera doesnt work for oyher applications, when i opened the divece manager, i didnt find the 'imaging devices' section, how can i add it to the list ?

Comment: Sorry cannot help you about this. Maybe you can try the advice from microsoft: [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13753/windows-10-camera-does-not-work）

Comment: Last week I accidently pushed the hot key on my laptop and forbid my built-in camera. 